# How to change DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I have installed dnsmasq and disabled systemd-resolved. dnsmasq will only use local hosts.dnsmasq and not forward any request.

```
addn-hosts=/home/users/hosts.dnsmasq
resolv-file=
```

The problem is that my /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten and nameserver is set to 127.0.0.1 which is dnsmasq and I would like to set it 8.8.8.8

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

How can I manually set name server to 8.8.8.8?

Configuring name servers to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base doesn't work.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Edit 1:
Changing server in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml won't make any difference. This was the default setting in OVH's VPS.

```
    nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 213.186.33.99
        search: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting DNSMASQ_EXCEPT in file /etc/default/dnsmasq

```
# If the resolvconf package is installed, dnsmasq will tell resolvconf
# to use dnsmasq under 127.0.0.1 as the system's default resolver.
# Uncommenting this line inhibits this behaviour.
#DNSMASQ_EXCEPT="lo"
```

`DNSMASQ_EXCEPT="lo"` will remove 127.0.0.1 from /etc/resolv.conf and you can manually add `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 0):

You tell one of the tools that manipulate `/etc/resolv.conf` to add it. If you use wifi see the network settings and tab ipv4; it has a DNS option there when you disable "automatic".

There is also [netplan](https://netplan.io/). There will be an example in `/etc/netplan` but a generic version using google DNS would be:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.121.1/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

`8.8.4.4` as the 2nd DNS.

Comment: That won't make any difference. 127.0.0.1 is still in resolv.conf.

Comment: and always will. that is localhost not a DNS name.

Comment: No it won't. Originally it was 213.186.33.99 which is in netplan but after installing dnsmasq it changed to 127.0.0.1. I don't want to use localhost as my DNS server. Dnsmasq is used to serve only specific NS records. I have done this in older Debian where you could just set DNS servers in /etc/resolc.conf.

Comment: and Ubuntu started using netplan a while back.